# Spring webflow issue with url params when invoked from word document

Tags: spring-webflow

I have a spring webflow application which is siteminder protected. The url typically has some params which the app uses to execute it's functionality. The implementation details are as follows -

1. When the url is invoked, i have an initial flow called authorize which takes the request params and validates them, If everything is good i have all the params in a javabean and this bean is stored in 'flowscope'
2. The above bean is passed to the next flows for various actions

This works fine when the url is invoked from the browser, but when the url is invoked from a word document we get the authentication dialog twice but the url params are not passed over to the browser.

Any one faced similar issue - please let me know

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Kiran C Sagi.

Comment: Try to log the url parameters, so when called from the Word document you can see what's wrong.